# recording dll APIs and then mimicking it

Tags: c++, windows, dll

Is there some tool that can record APIs in some c++ dll , and then playback them .

At our costumer site we have a machine with some vendor software that exposes it's functionality .
We wanted to record that dll and then mimic it back at the office .

Any idea how We can do that ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with `.net`?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov , probably you are right , shouldn't be there

Comment: OK, the necessary has been done :-)

Comment: No, scratch that option off your list.

Comment: Are you trying to steal your competitors' technology?

Comment: @ David Heffernan, not at all , just make simulation.

Comment: What's wrong with copying the dll to your office?

Comment: @pezcode , It is working only against actual machine that only our costumer has . And for debugging actual issue it is really nice to have all communication that came from dll and the ability to playback it against my application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start with [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) or its open-source equivalent [EasyHook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/). Your hook function can log the activity, and then back at the office you can write a replacement DLL that replays the activity.